# Iterator in variable and filenames

Tags: python-3.x, syntax, cycle

Is it possible to use iterator in this case?

```
for i in range (1,3):

a"$i", b"$i" = np.loadtxt('"$i".txt', unpack=True, usecols=[0, 1])

print(a"$i")
body"$i" = list(zip(a"$i",b"$i")) 
print(body"$i")
df"$i" = pd.DataFrame(body"$i", columns=["key"$i"", "val"$i""])
print(df"$i")
```

how to write i in variable and filenames? Thank you

```
    a"$i", b"$i" = np.loadtxt('"$i".txt', unpack=True, usecols=[0, 1])
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

It should be ekvivalent to:

```
a1, b1 = np.loadtxt('1.txt', unpack=True, usecols=[0, 1])
a2, b2 = np.loadtxt('2.txt', unpack=True, usecols=[0, 1])
print(a1)
print(b1)
body1 = list(zip(a1,b1)) 
print(body1)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(body1, columns=["key1", "val1"])
print(df1)

body2 = list(zip(a2,b2)) 
print(body2)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(body2, columns=["key2", "val2"])
print(df2)
```

Comment: When prose fails, show an expected input and output.

Comment: Error messages should be posted too if they exist

Comment: You can iterate over variables to access their values sequentially: `for i in a1, a2:` for example.  However, you *cannot* iterate over variables to assign to them - in the example above, assigning to `i` doesn't affect either of the original variables.  The better way to accomplish something like that is to have a single list (or other container) with all the values, rather than individual variables.

Comment: Thank you, could you please answer the question with example?

Comment: This is wrong, isn't it?
`a = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6]
b = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6]
for i in a:
    for j in b:
        i, j = np.loadtxt('1.txt', unpack=True, usecols=[0, 1])`